# Nginx NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID + Multi Wildcard Domain SSL Cert

Tags: ssl, nginx

This is the first time I've tried to use an SSL Certificate with Nginx. I have a StartCom SSL with 100 Domains all Wildcard enabled. Port 80 shows the site without issue but https/443 gives me the error - NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: I too see this issue with a wildcard COMODO certificate (3 year wildcard).  If I learn why, I will report back.